# Apps Script - Formatting the current date for timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script

I wish to format the current date as "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm".  formatDate allows me to format the date but I need to specify a timezone, per the following:

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")
```

This is almost what I want, but I want the result to be BST or GMT, as appropriate to the calendar.  What timezone should I specify to get the answer without further manipulation of the text date?  (I do have a clumsy workaround).  The problem caught me out with a timed batched process that runs at midnight upon our recent BST clock change where timestamps of 23:00 the previous day were applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script properties, make sure you've selected the correct time zone. Then, in your script, instead of using "GMT", use `Session.getScriptTimeZone()`.

```
function test() {
  var date1 = new Date("March 10, 2018 10:00");
  var date2 = new Date("March 11, 2018 10:00");
  Logger.log(date1); // Sat Mar 10 10:00:00 GMT-05:00 2018
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(date1, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")); // 2018/03/10 10:00
  Logger.log(date2); // Sun Mar 11 10:00:00 GMT-04:00 2018
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(date2, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")); // 2018/03/11 10:00
}
```

In the script editor, go to File > Project properties and set *your* time zone. (I used Eastern time for mine.)

[image]